# Get customer email address following stripe payment from payment link in pipedream webhook

Tags: stripe-payments, pipedream, mailerlite

I'm using pipedream to link stripe to mailerlite.
Customers can buy my product via a stripe payment link, which requires that they enter an email address.
I want to kick off my pipedream workflow when the payment has succeeded, and I want to access that email address.

In setting up the integration I've tried listening for the following events:

- `charge.succeeded`
- `payment_intent.succeeded`
- `checkout.session.completed`
- `order.payment_succeeded`

and submitting a payment in test mode, but not a single one of them contains the email address I entered when I submitted the payment.

How can I achieve my goal? Is there another event I should be looking for instead?

Thanks for any help offered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally I was testing the webhook by going to Payments (in test mode) and submitting a new one. No email address was being sent along with the `charge.succeeded` event, which was the event I really needed to look for.

However once I created a product (in test mode, again) and gave it a payment link, and tested that with one of the [test card numbers](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses) then bought it via the link, the event I received did have the email address I used to purchase it along with it.